# what does --exclude do in tar command when use like this "tar cvfz ../xxx --exclude './yyy/**' "?

Tags: shell, unix

I see this command : 
`tar cvfz ../xxx --exclude './yyy/**'`

xxx and yyy is just directory.

Now, I can't understand what is ****** after --exclude argument?

I think this pattern is part shell!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**` means "* recursively" (in subdirectories, not only in the directory proper,) including slashes.

```
foo/**/bar
```

means "bar" in any subdirectory of "foo".

Answer (score 1):

Fro the tar man page:

```
 --exclude pattern
     Do not process files or directories that match the specified pattern.
```

So for your case it is **excluding all the files & sub-directories** in `yyy/` directory and further down to be archived by specifying exclude pattern as `./yyy/**'`.